# AWS: Can a Beanstalk instance be deployed with a Postgres RDS?

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sails.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anyone know whether an Elastic Beanstalk (EB) instance can be deployed with a Postgres RDS?

While Postgres is one of four options for RDS, the EB doc curiously only mentions the three others: MS SQL, Oracle and MySQL, but no Postgres.

Context: my current goal is to deploy a simple Django web site and later on possibly compare its development/maintenance ease and performance with a Sails.js web site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes postrgres is supported.

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/12/11/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-background-task-handling-and-rds-postgresql-support/

It could be a miss in the doc page. Setting "DBEngine" option setting to "postgres" should work.

Let me know if you need more help setting up postgres.

Comment: I would appreciate a sample option settings list for deploying a postgres rds database with the eb application.  I cannot get one launched using something like:('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBAllocatedStorage', '5'),
            ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBEngine', 'postgresql'),
            ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBEngineVersion', '9.3'),
            ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBInstanceClass', 'db.t2.micro'),
            ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBPassword', self.rds_password),
            ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBUser', self.rds_username),

Comment: Well I submitted that comment with the option settings formatted like that by mistake because I hit the enter key, but I guess is readable enough

Comment: If you would prefer to answer in a different question, I've asked one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043706/how-to-use-boto-to-launch-an-elastic-beanstalk-with-an-rds-resource

Comment: Responded to the other answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Rohit Banga, Do you have any advice on troubleshooting this issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732474/django-haystack-with-elasticsearch-cannot-find-database-when-rebuilding-index