# How to use boto to launch an elastic beanstalk with an rds resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto

How can I launch an elastic beanstalk application with a RDS database using boto?

I am sending the following option settings in my create_environment call but the RDS db is not launched:

```
    ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBAllocatedStorage', '5'),
    ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBEngine', 'postgresql'),
    ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBEngineVersion', '9.3'),
    ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBInstanceClass', 'db.t2.micro'),
    ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBPassword', self.rds_password),
    ('aws:rds:dbinstance', 'DBUser', self.rds_username),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specifying option settings is not sufficient to create an RDS. The option settings are used to configure settings for RDS.
To create an RDS along with your beanstalk environment you have three options:

1. Use the console
2. Use EB CLI
3. Use an ebextension to specify an RDS resource

First one is pretty simple.
For the second one you can follow the tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html).

I recently responded on the third possibility [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25963800/161628).

Comment: Is it possible to create the RDS instance from the EB CLI anymore?

Comment: Yes see eb create --database option in the latest CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html